# Polymer: Listen to "scroll"-event of core-header-panel

Tags: polymer

i'm trying to listen to the "scroll"-event of the core-header-panel but there seems to be a problem with my code. My event-listener is not working yet.

```
window.addEventListener("polymer-ready", function(e) {
    var coreHeaderPanel = document.querySelector("core-header-panel");
    coreHeaderPanel.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

The coreHeaderPanel obj is found but i quess its the wrong event name i'm registering the listener for.

Is "scroll" the correct event name? According to google docs it is
[Google Docs: core-header-panel](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-header-panel)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Was a bug in my core-header-panel.html.
Fixed with [fixes #7][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/Polymer/core-header-panel/commit/a9ae343ba10676590cf6e049352ec19bdfdd99e5

Comment: Don't forget to either delete the question or answer it and mark it accepted